# How do you check if something is NaN and it is not equal to a string?

Tags: javascript, string

I'm trying out this code and it's not working please help!

Here's the code:

```js
var test = "3";

function printIsNaN(value) {
  var bool = document.getElementById("booleanValue");
  if (isNaN(value) === true) {
    bool.style.color = "green";
    bool.innerHTML = "true";
  } else if (isNaN(value) === false) {
    bool.style.color = "red";
    bool.innerHTML = "false";
  }
}

printIsNaN(test);
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en-US">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>Stackoverflow Question</title>
  <script src="something.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
  <!-- START OF THE DOCUMENT -->
  <span id="booleanValue"></span>
</body>
</html>
```

Thanks if you can help PLEASE!!!!!!!!

Comment: *is not equal to string* - do you mean it's not `typeof` string?

Comment: Or... `Number.isNaN`?

Comment: What is expected result?

Comment: [works fine for me](https://jsfiddle.net/fh1Ly78m/)

Comment: What is not working?

Comment: The `Number.isNaN()` function is the same as the `isNaN()` function.

Comment: Why did you delete the entire body of the question?  Now if people google about this and come across the question, they won't be able to see the original question that the answers are answering.

Comment: Sorry RJM........

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you could use ParseInt() to change the string into an integer

```
    function printIsNaN(value) {
  var bool = document.getElementById("booleanValue");
  if (isNaN(parseInt(value))) {
    console.log("nope");
  } else if (!isNaN(parseInt(value))) {
    console.log("yep");
  }
}
```

hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

In ES6 there is a function on the Number object called `isNaN` it test the value if it's a true `NaN` (Number and not a string)

You can implement that function like this:

```
if (!Number.isNaN) {
    Number.isNaN = function(n) {
        return n !== n;
    };
}
```

It relies on the face that `NaN` is the only value that doesn't equal to itself.

Source: https://github.com/getify/You-Dont-Know-JS/blob/master/types%20%26%20grammar/ch2.md